# mongodb - command 'show collection' doesn't show anything

Tags: mongodb

I switched my db properly and also confirmed that there is a document in my collection but I cannot find any collection by 'show collection' command.

[image]

Can I know the reason?

Comment: what is your mongodb version ? are you running a local mongodb instance ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check your Mongo shell version and MongoDB version are compatible.

Refer to this [JIRA ticket](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-16728) which has the similar issue reported. The root cause of the problem was the Mongo shell version and MongoDB version were not compatible.

**To get Mongo Shell version:-**

Go to the bin folder and execute `mongo` command which will print the Mongo shell version in the first line.

[image: MongoDB shell version]

**To get MongoDB version:-**

```
db.version()
```

Comment: My mongodb shell version was 2.6, so I updated it to 3.6 and the command works well now. Thanks!